# Automated PDF Creation from URL

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a PDF library that one can use to automate creating PDFs from URLs? The current approach I use is to "Print" a page and select a PDF plugin like PrimoPDF to generate the PDF document but I was wanting to automate that.

Answer (score 5):

[ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com) can do it

Answer (score 3):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) generates the most accurate PDFs out of web pages that I have ever found. It renders them in WebKit and converts this to PDF, so the PDF will look exactly like the web page, including all styles and other fancy things.

Just use it like this:

```
wkpdfhtmltopdf http://www.whatever.com/page.html page.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what platform you are on

Windows - Websupergoo's ABC PDF

http://www.websupergoo.com/

*nix - Prince XML
http://www.princexml.com/overview/

Answer (score 0):

I've also used ABC PDF (from classic ASP) and found it very good.